# detect height of element through attribute javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` that has a certain **attribute**. Is it possible to give this **attribute** the height of my element dynamically? for example:

HTML

```
<div data-size="this.style.height"></div>
```

OUTPUT

```
<div data-size="400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, select all the elements with `data-size` attribute and you can do like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-size]').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-size', $(this).outerHeight() + "px");
  });
});
```

```css
div {border: 1px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-size="this.style.size">
  <div style="height: 300px;"></div>
</div>
<div data-size="this.style.size">
  <div style="height: 25px;"></div>
</div>
<div data-size="this.style.size">
  <div style="height: 50px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it will return : data-size="400", don't forget to add +"px"

Comment: @enguerranws Done. Updated the code with the fiddle too! `:P` Works!

Comment: You don't actually need the this.style.size in there anymore either. Maybe that part of it might be good if you did `onload="this.setAttribute("data-size", this.style.size);"`although getting the innerHeight of the object using pure JS is a bit harder :)

Comment: @somethinghere I just literally copied it from the OP's post,.

Answer (score 2):

In plain JavaScript:

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-size]'), 0).forEach(function (elem) {
    elem.setAttribute('data-size', window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).height);
});
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute).
- [`Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the height of the element using jQuery as following,

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('[data-size]').each(function(){
          $(this).height($(this).attr("data-size"));
      });
 });
```